# Count the time taken till iOS App fully loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c

*After a brief search, strangely I don't find any similar question.*

I would like to count the time taken till iOS App to load completely, since App Launch. **My question is:** Is the following approach the most accurate (well, we can't be 100% accurate I think)?

In App Delegate, add the variable:

```
NSDate *start_date;
```

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, add at line 1:

```
start_date = [NSDate date];
```

In some function representing app loaded completely, add this:

```
NSTimeInterval time_taken = [start_date timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

But is there any notification in `NSNotificationCenter` configured to detect the App has completed all the loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do is track the start timestamp in `main` and track the end time in your root view controller's `viewDidAppear` method.

Keep in mind that this doesn't include the time it takes the OS to load and launch your app to the point that `main` is called. There is no way to track that time.

There is no notification. You need to determine what it mean to be done loading such as what I suggested earlier.

Comment: I rarely modify `main.m`. How can I access a variable in `main.m` from App Delegate or any other View Controller class?

Comment: You will have to define a global variable somewhere so you can access it both from main and whatever class you wish to track the "end time" in.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding an `+initialize` class method to your app delegate. That method will be called before the instance of the view controller gets created.

Add an NSDate global variable (in the .m file, outside the implementation) and set it to [NSDate date]. Then once you've fully set up your user interface and are ready to respond, compare the start NSDate to the current time.

Comment: how does this `+initialize` different than `applicationDidFinishLaunching` ?

Comment: It is called much earlier in the application's launch cycle, before the app delegate object is even allocated. applicationDidFinishLaunching is called after the system is finished launching your app (thus the name.)